# Reversal Badge text bug?

Tags: support, badges

The [Blog Post for the Reversal Badge](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/07/reversal-and-pundit-badges/) states (in part):

> `Provided an answer upvoted 20 or more times to a question that was downvoted 5 or more times. (gold)`

Yet the text of the badge states:

> `Provided answer of +20 score to a question of -5 score`

Which one is it? Is it +20 score? or 20 upvotes?

I ask because I recently answered [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1346796/getting-row-from-gridview-in-dev-express/1346898#1346898)  , which was at `-5` when I answered and received multiple upvotes for it; but I apparently haven't triggered the criteria for the [Reversal badge](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/badges/41/reversal).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is +20 score for an answer on a question that makes it to -5 score. This is typically how it happens even though you see in many instances where the "X number of upvotes" is the text for the trigger. I have always seen it as "+X" and not "X upvotes"

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/95/reversal), you can take a look at people who have earned this badge

Comment: The badges are awared by a scheduled run of a stored proc, right? Would follow that it is +X if this is the case, unless the data model (which I admittedly haven't looked at yet) stores vote history instead of vote accumulation.

Comment: It used to be done by an ASP.NET Service; I don't know what does it now.

Comment: correct, 20 score.